# .Net Razor pages - How to redirect to external URL with some POST data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a .NET 6 Solution with 2 Razor pages projects. They are called Application1 and Application2. The two applications run under different port numbers.

**My Goal:**

I have a button in Application1, when clicked, I want to redirect user to Application2, but I want to send some values from Application1 to Application2. I am not allowed to use URL Query Strings as those can be easily manipulated.

**What I have Tried**

I have tried to post the required values in the 2nd application using this approach:

```
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public void OnPostRedirect()
    {
        string url = "https://localhost:7075/index";

        string MyDataFirstName = "Adam";
        string MyDataLanguage = "English";
        string MyDataTokenCode = "ABCD1234XYZ789";
        
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "firstname", MyDataFirstName },
            { "language", MyDataLanguage },
            { "tokencode", MyDataTokenCode }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;       

        Response.Redirect(url);

    }
```

**My Question is:**

1. Is this approach Ok? If not then what could be the correct approach?
2. How do I retrieve these values in the 2nd application? I am not able to retrieve these values there. I tried to inspect the `Request` object in the Index page's `OnGet()` method in the 2nd application. But I could not find these values there.

Comment: Do not check `OnGet()` when you're using POST ! Use `OnPost()` instead!

Comment: In OnPost() the debugger never hits. It hits OnGet() only. Why this is happening ?

Comment: Ok, that happens, because `Response.Redirect(url);` will redirect the browser (which will be a GET request and that is what you're debugging). Don't know what happens to your POST. Might be because you make a dead-lock with the `.Result`. Try using `await` instead.

Comment: Reading the question again, I think you are doing it wrong. You should write some javascript and let the browser POST the data to your second application using 'submit' , then it is automatically 'redirected' to the second app. (check the related questions below).

Comment: Do you config CORS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a model to retrive `FormUrlEncodedContent`, and the calling URL should be "https://localhost:7075/home/index" ,and you may need to add '.GetAwaiter().GetResult();" when use postasync in a none-async method. 
You can try the following code.

app1

```
        public void test()
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string url = "https://localhost:7181/home/index";

            string MyDataFirstName = "Adam";
            string MyDataLanguage = "English";
            string MyDataTokenCode = "ABCD1234XYZ789";

            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "firstname", MyDataFirstName },
                { "language", MyDataLanguage },
                { "tokencode", MyDataTokenCode }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            client.PostAsync(url, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();    

            Response.Redirect(url);
        }
```

app2

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string tokencode { get; set; }   
    }
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index([FromForm] MyModel model)
        {
            var firstname = model.firstname;
            Console.WriteLine(firstname); //you could see the value in CMD.
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Test
[image]
Actually, if not using javascript, you should create another method rather than "index" to receive data, then save them to database . When app1 go to the step of redirect to app2/index. You would be able to retrive the data from database in index method.